# Grouping elements in list (python)

Tags: python, list

I want to group items in a list, I've tried something, but it didn't work as planned.

This is the example of result that I want:

```
list = ['apple', 'apple', 'banana', 'banana']
groupedList = ['2 x apple', '2 x banana']

list2 = ['dog', 'dog', 'dog', 'cat', 'cat']
groupedList2 = ['3 x dog', '2 x cat']
```

As I've mentioned I don't have an idea how to solve it and I'm stuck now. Can somebody please help me?

Comment: checkout ``collections.Counter``

Comment: If it didn't work as planned, how did it work then?

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
from collections import Counter
x = ['apple', 'apple', 'banana', 'banana']
result = [f'{v} x {k}' for k, v in Counter(x).items()]
print(result)
```

Output:

```
['2 x apple', '2 x banana']
```